# Recursion in ARM Assembly to Print 100

Tags: c, assembly, recursion, arm

I'm very confused on how to recursively implement a method to print 100 (1..2..3..100) using ARM assembly.. I have the C code to do this and the C is very simple, but the assembly is a lot more and I have no clue how to do it.

Please help?

Thanks!

```
print100_recursive_ARM:
push {r4-r11, ip, lr}
CMP r0, #0
BEQ print_zero
SUB r0, r0, #1
BL print100_recursive_ARM
pop {r4-r11, ip, lr}
B print_num

print_num:
print_zero:
constant: .ascii "%d "
Print_ARM:
MOV r1, r0
LDR r0, =constant
BL printf

end:
pop {r4-r11, ip, lr}
BX lr
```

And this doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should actually try this instead of asking someone to do the whole thing for you.  What format do you want the output in?  Can you make an ARM assembly program that just outputs "0"?  Can you make a recursive program that outputs the number in unary (the number 3 gets printed as "111")?  What prevents you from doing decimal?  When you get stuck doing one of these you should be able to ask a more specific question and show your code.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of different ARM processors so which one do you want to use?

Comment: All i know is that it's arm assembly.. I don't know the specifics because we were never really told.. as I didn't know there were anything more than just ARM assembly.. i'm using an emulator for raspberrypi and can't really copy what I have :/

Comment: The only thing that i'm wanting it to do is print 1 2 3 4 5 up to 100 recursively... I have it in C, but translating it is way too difficult.

Comment: Since you have it in C, use the compiler to generate assembler output (if possible) or look at the code in a debugger.

Comment: It doesn't compile to the right assembly... I posted what I have above and it's not right.. someone please help.

Comment: The code is posted...........

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a sufficient explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Dirty trick: Write it in C, compile with e.g. `gcc -S source.c`, and analyze how the compiler did it (in `source.s` now). How to call/return, how to handle local variables, is typically complex. This way you get working assembler source to study or modify.